# Pause/Freeze a scene with a trackable active in vuforia unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing an app with vuforia Cloud Recos. I want to add the feature of allowing the user to pause the page so she does not have to keep pointing the device on the target to view the trackable. This is pretty useful when I want to show texts. Is there anyway to achieve that on Unity3D ? A good example is Microsoft's Here City Lens app which includes a button to pause the page as the screenshot shows;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a screenshot of the screen and apply it to an Image UI object. That is if you do not need the camera feed anymore.

If you need interaction with the elements, I would only take a screenshot of the camera feed without items. Get AR camera transform, apply it to a new camera, disable AR camera.Then apply the screenshot to a background plane covering the whole screen. Keep items on as well and they do not listen to Vuforia anymore. You are pretty much recreating a basic Unity scene. The items should not be moving with Vuforia, the camera is. So they are still in the middle and you need to know where was the camera when you took the shot. Your scene is complete

Comment: Thank you, it makes pretty much sense to me. I will try that and will paste a code snippet for anyone interested.